# Epson perfection v30 scanner installation problem

Tags: installation, scanner, epson

Further to my Epson V30 scanner installation problems, below is the message when the key driver file installation is attempted. I see many people have successfully installed their V30.

Has anyone seen this error and got around it?

I tried the help from Dan and still no luck. If I am not following etiquette please forgive me as I am new to Linux and the forum. So I will hope I can learn more.

```
root@ubuntu:~#  dpkg -i /home/john/Downloads/iscan_2.29.1-5~usb0.1.ltdl7_i386.deb
Selecting previously unselected package iscan.
(Reading database ... 157309 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking iscan (from .../iscan_2.29.1-5~usb0.1.ltdl7_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of iscan:
 iscan depends on iscan-data.
 iscan depends on libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.14.1); however:
  Package libgtk2.0-0:i386 is not installed.
 iscan depends on libltdl7 (>= 2.2.4); however:
  Package libltdl7:i386 is not installed.
 iscan depends on libsane (>= 1.0.11-3); however:
  Package libsane:i386 is not installed.
 iscan depends on libusb-0.1-4 (>= 2:0.1.12); however:
  Package libusb-0.1-4:i386 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing iscan (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the scanner with the application **Simple Scan**

If not works, install follows:

```
sudo apt-get install netcat-openbsd netcat-traditional
```

Then try to run Simple Scan.